# Extracting data from json in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest

I have ajax connection with controller

```
function changeEmail() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        ...
        error: function (error) {
            var obj = error.responseText;
            console.log('Error: ' + obj);
            console.log('Obj length: ' +  obj.fieldErrors.length);
        }
    });
}
```

Which in case of error returns a list of errors in json.
However, he is not able to refer to this list.
https://zapodaj.net/e6354b8c71f4c.png.html 
I do not know, for example, how to refer to the first element of a list to the

> message

variable

Comment: You may need to parse JSON response before. Try `var obj =JSON.parse(error.responseText)`

Comment: is it a JSON or value is returned as String? You might need to `JSON.parse` it

Comment: Where is the Java code?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the content-type response from your server, the default response type is probably text/html or some other incorrect content-type.

You have two ways to fix this.
First, you can set `obj = JSON.parse(error.responseText)`

or, you can make sure that the server sets the correct content-type on errors as well.